# Linear independence of $(x\sin x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ and $(x\sin x)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Could you tell me why  $(x\sin x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ and $(x\sin x)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ are lineraly independent?

I've tried $\alpha(x \sin x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} + \beta (x\sin x)^{\frac{n+1}{2}} =0$

$(x\sin x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(\alpha + \beta (x\sin x))=0$

but I don't know how that implies linear independence.

$x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, so $(x\sin x) \ge 0$ on this interval.

Comment: I've just added it in the question.

Comment: I doubt if we can use an induction on $n>1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha(x \sin x)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} + \beta (x\sin x)^{\frac{n+1}{2}} =0$ (the zero function), clearly it cannot happen that *exactly one* of $\alpha,\beta$ is zero. If both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are nonzero, then by rearranging terms, we have $x\sin x=-\alpha/\beta$ for all $x$ such that $x\sin x\neq0$. I think it is easy enough to rule out this case.

Comment: Could you tell me why we can rule out this case, because that has been my problem all along.

Comment: @Sandy You can easily find two different $x$ such that the values of $x\sin x$ are **different** (hence they cannot be both equal to $-\alpha/\beta$, regardless of what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are) and nonzero.